# Is this implication correct?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, divisibility

Let $a$ and $b$ two coprime integer numbers. Then there exist $u₁$ and $v₁$ such that $$au_1+bv_1=1\tag1$$

Let us consider an equation of the form:
$$ah+bd=g\tag2$$

where $h$ is an unknown multivariate integer polynomial and $d$ is known multivariate integer polynomial. From $(1)$ we get
$$au_1g+bv_1g=g\tag3$$

**Then by comparison** of $(3)$ with $(2)$ we get
$$ah=au_1g$$
and

$$bd=bv_1g$$

that is,

$$h=u_1g$$
and

$$d=v_1g$$

**My question is**: Is this implication true? I cannot make a decision on that.

Comment: What is the basis of ur comparison?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: There is no basis. Just an idea to do that

Comment: BTW what is $g$?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: $g$ is a multivariate polynomial.

Comment: At most, we can conclude $h-u_1g$ and $d-v_1g$ are coprime.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: How did you find that

Comment: Even if we fix a solution of $$au+bv=1$$ (Note that there infinite many solutions for every coprime pair $(a,b)$) , I do not see how this comparison should work in general, Even for coprime polynomials $h$ and $d$ there should be a counterexample.

Comment: Just subtract (2) from (3), and use the fact (1).

Comment: @SchrodingersCat: Than you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. For example if $a\ne 0\ne b$ and  $0\ne h=-bd$ and $0\ne d=ah.$  Then  $$0=g=ah+bd=au_1g+bv_1g$$ but $$ah\ne 0=au_1g \quad \text {and  }\; bd\ne 0=bv_1g.$$